# php laravel echo blade html mistake

Tags: php, html, laravel

am try to echo this.

```
echo "<td><a href='{{ URL::to('index/watch/' . $tmpd) }}''>$tmpd </a></td>";
```

output must be http://localhost:8000/index/watch/myvar

but it also http://localhost:8000/%7B%7B%20URL::to(

what is my echo mistake

Comment: Don't mix blade template symantics `{{...}}` with PHP echo statements

Comment: I'm not sure if you've run across Laracasts yet (or if you have and you hate them (or if anyone else on the internet has and they hate them, in which case this comment will probably get downvoted into oblivion)) but Jeff put together what felt to me like [a pretty solid intro to Blade](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/3) which you might want to look into. I found the rest of the series helpful as well when I started with Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always good practice to use laravel helpers. The below code generates the html link that you are looking for.

```
echo '<td>'.link_to('index/watch/'.$tmpd.'', $tmpd).'</td>';
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Check out these laravel helper funcitons https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls

Answer (score 2):

As Mark Baker said don't include the whole statement in an `echo` but also for the url you need to use the unescaped tag `{!! !!}`:

```
<td><a href='{!! URL::to('index/watch/' . $tmpd) !!}'>{{ $tmpd }}</a></td>
```

Comment: can i use with php echo ??

Comment: no you cant, {{ }} (aka blade tags) are the php echo.

Comment: The point of using a template system like blade is so that you don't have to use `echo` statements.